# Duplicate action of two select list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to duplicate the action of two select lists, for example if you select a value for the first one, the other one should be automatically updated.

This is my code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descripcion, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-inline md-form mr-auto">
                <select class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" onchange = "return GetChange(this);">
                    <option>Texto 1</option>
                    <option>Texto 2</option>
                    <option>Texto 3</option>
                </select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descripcion)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.descripcion, new {onChange = "return GetValue(this);", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-inline md-form mr-auto">
                <select class="form-control" id="descripcionx" name="descripcionx" onchange="return GetValue(this);">
                    <option value="20">Texto 1</option>
                    <option value="30">Texto 2</option>
                    <option value="40">Texto 3</option>
                </select>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.descripcion)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This my javascript function:

```
function GetChange(ctr) { 
    var i = $("#descripcion option:selected").index(); 
    $("#descripcionx").val(i); 
}
```

Comment: would you add more details what you mean: "double the action of two select list for example if you selected one that automatically selects the following". What does **following** means?. I believe this is `asp.net`.

Comment: For example I have two combobox, if I select "Text 2", the next combobox automatically selects "Tex 2".

Comment: I need a function in js that does that please :(

Comment: That basically means that you want to set the same value for another dropdown.

Did you try calling onchange() function on select and setting the value to the required value.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? It would be good to show us what you have tried.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini                 
function GetChange(ctr) {
            var i = $("#descripcion option:selected").index();
            $("#descripcionx").val(i);
        }

Comment: This doesn't work for me either....................................................................... function GetChange(ctr) {
            var i = document.getElementById("descripcion").selectedIndex;
            $("#descripcionx").SelectedIndex(i);
 
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update it with position then you should do this

```js
function changeDropdown(e){
  var value = $("#descripcion option:selected").index();
  $("#descripcionx").prop('selectedIndex', value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-inline md-form mr-auto">
                <select class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" onchange = "changeDropdown(this);">
                    <option>Texto 1</option>
                    <option>Texto 2</option>
                    <option>Texto 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="form-inline md-form mr-auto">
                <select class="form-control" id="descripcionx" name="descripcionx" onchange="changeDropdown(this);">
                    <option value="20">Texto 1</option>
                    <option value="30">Texto 2</option>
                    <option value="40">Texto 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But in this case, both of your dropdown `option` order must be same. Better to use same `value` attribute in both dropdown. Then you can change it simply by this

```
function changeDropdown(e){
  var value = $("#descripcion option:selected").val();
  $("#descripcionx").val(value);
}
```